# Populate a SELECT dropdown list with JSON data using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to populate a SELECT dropdown list with JSON data using JavaScript.

I have sample data:

```
sampledata  =  [{ "Districtname": "CENTRAL DELHI", "ID": 1 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH DELHI", "ID": 2 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 3 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 4 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH DELHI", "ID": 5 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 6 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 7 }, { "Districtname": "WEST DELHI", "ID": 8 }]
```

```
success: function(data) {
    var distList = data.d;
    console.log(distList);
    //consoleoutput =  [{ "Districtname": "CENTRAL DELHI", "ID": 1 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH DELHI", "ID": 2 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 3 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 4 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH DELHI", "ID": 5 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 6 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 7 }, { "Districtname": "WEST DELHI", "ID": 8 }]
    var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Distic</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < distList.length; i++) {
        s += '<option value="' + distList[i].ID + '">' + distList[i].Districtname + '</option>';
    }
    $("#dist").html(s);

}
```

I tried another approach:

```
$.each(distList, function (key, value) {
  $('#dist').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
});
```

but I got:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"Districtname":"CENTRAL.................... ,{"Districtname":"WEST DELHI","ID":8}]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you provide all the relevant code? It shows error related to usage of `in` keyword but no `in` used in the code you provided

Comment: why would you imagine `$.each(distList, function (key, value)` would *know* that you want to use `value.ID` and `value.Districtname` as values for `key` and `value`?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in [{"Districtname":"CENTRAL DELHI","ID":1},{"Districtname":"NORTH DELHI","ID":2},{"Districtname":"NORTH EAST DELHI","ID":3},{"Districtname":"NORTH WEST DELHI","ID":4},{"Districtname":"SOUTH DELHI","ID":5},{"Districtname":"SOUTH EAST DELHI","ID":6},{"Districtname":"SOUTH WEST DELHI","ID":7},{"Districtname":"WEST DELHI","ID":8}]

Comment: `$.each(distList, function (key, value)` - when you loop over your array like that, then key would be thenumeric index (0, 1, 2, ...), and value would be the objects from your array, `{ "Districtname": "CENTRAL DELHI", "ID": 1 }`, `{ "Districtname": "NORTH DELHI", "ID": 2 }`, etc. Trying to concatenate _those_ into a string, makes little sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
sampledata  =  [{ "Districtname": "CENTRAL DELHI", "ID": 1 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH DELHI", "ID": 2 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 3 }, { "Districtname": "NORTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 4 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH DELHI", "ID": 5 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 6 }, { "Districtname": "SOUTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 7 }, { "Districtname": "WEST DELHI", "ID": 8 }]

//Instead of:

/*
    var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a Distic</option>';
    for (var i = 0; i < sampledata.length; i++) {
        s += '<option value="' + sampledata[i].ID + '">' + sampledata[i].Districtname + '</option>';
    }
   $('#dist').html(s);
   
*/


  // Default option at select could be 
  // place inside the select of static html.

  // To iterate "JSON" known as Object inside JS
  // Try to use for(let district of sampledata)
  const $selectElement = document.querySelector('#dist');
  for(let district of sampledata){
   //New HTMLOptionElement
   let $option = document.createElement('option');
   $option.value = district.ID;
   $option.innerText = district.Districtname;
   //Add option
   $selectElement.appendChild($option);
  }
```

```css
select {
 width: 300px;
 padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<select name="districts" id="dist">
 <!-- loaded by js -->
  <option value="-1">Please Select a District</option>
</select>
```

References:
[For..of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: It works, but this will lead to huge performances issues and even freezing of the tab with a list bigger than few elements, inside a real webpage with a lot of others elements. First, you are calling `document.querySelector` at each loop, this means parsing the whole DOM each time. Then you use `innerHTML +=`, this is is a huge performance hit, as the whole DOM, has again, to be calculated at each loop. Lastly, you shown how to use `for..of`, that's great, but beside the readability, this simply provides nothing much. There is many ways to create iterations, `forEach`, `map()`, etc, etc.

Comment: thanks @NVRM to reply, that's true I try it to be simple but I forgot to apply the performance, I did some changes I hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `in` operator only works on objects. You are using it on a string. Make sure your value is an object before you using *$.each*. In this specific case, you have to parse the JSON:

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(sampledata ), ...)
```

Furthermore, there is an easier way to populate data on HTML select using JavaScript.

Have a look on below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Select Control Population</title>
</head>
<body>

  <label for="districtSelect">Select District:</label>
  <select id="districtSelect"></select>

  <script>
    // Your data
    const districts = [
      { "Districtname": "CENTRAL DELHI", "ID": 1 },
      { "Districtname": "NORTH DELHI", "ID": 2 },
      { "Districtname": "NORTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 3 },
      { "Districtname": "NORTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 4 },
      { "Districtname": "SOUTH DELHI", "ID": 5 },
      { "Districtname": "SOUTH EAST DELHI", "ID": 6 },
      { "Districtname": "SOUTH WEST DELHI", "ID": 7 },
      { "Districtname": "WEST DELHI", "ID": 8 }
    ];

    // Get the select element
    const selectElement = document.getElementById("districtSelect");

    // Iterate over the data and create option elements
    districts.forEach(district => {
      const optionElement = document.createElement("option");
      optionElement.value = district.ID;
      optionElement.textContent = district.Districtname;
      selectElement.appendChild(optionElement);
    });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks Selaka , what is wrong in this code $.each(distList, function (key, value) {
  $('#dist').append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
});

Comment: Nothing wrong in this code.. In you code  The `in` operator only works on objects. You are using it on a string. Make sure your value is an object before you using $.each. In this specific case, you have to parse the JSON: $.each(JSON.parse(sampledata  ), ...);

Comment: It's not appropriate to ask for an upvote and accept. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417578/9473764

Comment: @Nick thanks for pointing out. Will not ask for this further

Comment: @SelakaNanayakkara: you have continued to

Answer (score 1):

This works for me -

```
// jQuery
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (index, value) {
    // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
    $(control).append('<option value="' + value.ID + '">' + value.Districtname + '</option>');
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This code works for me:

```
let distList = JSON.parse(data.d);

// Method 1

var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select a District</option>';
for (var i = 0; i < distList.length; i++) {
    s += '<option value="' + distList[i].ID + '">' + distList[i].Districtname + '</option>';
}
$("#dist").html(s);


// Method 2

$("#dist").html("");
$.each(distList, function (key, value) {
    $('#dist').append('<option>' + distList[key].Districtname + '</option>');
});
```